# ureadahead: Error while tracing. Possible kernel patch problem?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

Running the `ureadahead` in the command line results in this error:

```
#/usr/sbin/ureadahead
ureadahead: Error while tracing: No such file or directory
```

I got the following messages from strace

```
open("/var/lib/ureadahead/pack", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/sys/kernel/debug/tracing", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOATIME) = 3
openat(3, "events/fs/do_sys_open/enable", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(3)                                = 0
write(2, "ureadahead: Error while tracing:"..., 59ureadahead: Errorwhile tracing: No such file or directory
) = 59
exit_group(5)                           = ?
+++ exited with 5 +++
```

Does this line

```
openat(3, "events/fs/do_sys_open/enable", O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

mean that the kernel is not correctly patched? Should patched the kernel first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that error means you need to apply the appropriate [patch](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/ureadahead/wily/view/head:/0001-trace-add-trace-events-for-open-exec-an.patch) to your kernel; that patch adds the ability to trace certain filesystem events, and exposes files in the kernel's `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events` directory.

Comment: Thx, I am sure that I patched the kernel already. Investigating why it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: My case is related to kernel initialization. I will accept your answer as it is more general.